# The unit disk with pseudo hyperbolic distance is complete space

Tags: complex-analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

The pseudo-hyperbolic distance on the unit disk $D$ is defined as:
$$\rho(z,w)=\left|\dfrac{z-w}{1-\bar wz}\right|.$$

I need to prove that $(D,\rho(z,w))$ is complete space.

I know that a metric space is called complete if every Cauchy sequence converges, but I really don't know how to prove that this space is complete, could you give me some idea?

Comment: one idea is like this: by Cauchy there is $n_0$ st $\left|\dfrac{z_n-z_m}{1-\bar z_nz_m}\right| <1/2, n,m \ge n_0$; but now if $r=\limsup |z_n|$, the above implies that $r<1$ since if $z_{n_k} \to e^{i\theta}$ passing to the limit we get $1=\rho(z_n,e^{i\theta}) \le 1/2$ so $|z_n| \le r_1<1$ for all $n$ and then $\rho(z,w) \le C|z-w|$ with $C=\frac{1}{1-r_1^2}$ and the completeness of the Euclidean metric gives the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me expand on @Conrad's comment, for future readers. But first, some key observations:

$(i)$ Denote $d_2$ the usual euclidean distance on $\mathbb{C}$, i.e. $d_2(z,w):=|z-w|$. Taking the restriction of this to $\mathbb{D}$, $(\mathbb{D},d_2)$ is a metric subspace of $(\mathbb{C},d_2)$.

$(ii)$ Because $\mathbb{D}$ is not closed in $\mathbb{C}, (\mathbb{D},d_2)$ is not a complete metric space.

$(iii)$ If someone is wondering why $\rho$ is indeed a metric on $\mathbb{D}$, please consult [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311833/proving-pseudo-hyperbolic-distance-is-distance?rq=1).

$(iv)$ It is not hard to see that $\rho$ and $d_2$ are continuous (with respect to the standard topology of $(\mathbb{C},d_2)$) in each variable. Actually, the metric of a metric space is always continuous.

$(v)$ We have the following inequality between the metrics involved:

$$\forall z,w\in\mathbb{D},\rho(z,w)=\frac{|z-w|}{|1-z\overline{w}|}\geq\frac{|z-w|}{1+|z\overline{w}|}\geq\frac{|z-w|}{2}=\frac{d_2(z,w)}{2}\Rightarrow \rho\geq\frac{d_2}{2}.\tag{1}$$

---

Now, start with a Cauchy sequence $(z_n)_{n\geq 1}\subseteq (\mathbb{D},\rho)$. Due to $(1)$, it means that the same sequence is also Cauchy in $(\mathbb{D},d_2)$, or in $(\mathbb{C},d_2)$. The complex numbers form a complete metric space, and thus our sequence is convergent in $\mathbb{C}$. Its limit must be in the closure of the unit disk, so let's say $z_n\to z_0\in \overline{\mathbb{D}}$. We have two disjoint cases:

$(i)$ $\color{blue}{z_0\in\partial\mathbb{D}}$. We will show that this case is impossible. There is an important fact here: if we allow one argument of $\rho$ to be on the unit circle, then we have:

$$\forall z\in\mathbb{D},\forall w\in\partial\mathbb{D},\rho(z,w)=\frac{|z-w|}{|1-z\overline{w}|}=\frac{|w(z\overline{w}-1)|}{|1-z\overline{w}|}=|w|=1.$$

Because $(z_n)_n$ is Cauchy, there is $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$\forall m,n\geq n_0,\rho(z_m,z_n)=\frac{|z_m-z_n|}{|1-z_m\overline{z_n}|}<\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow 1=\rho(z_0,z_n)=\lim_{m\to\infty}\rho(z_m,z_n)\leq\frac{1}{2},$$
and this is a contradiction.

$(ii)$ $\color{blue}{z_0\in\mathbb{D}}$. Therefore, $\lim\sup|z_n|=\lim_{n\to\infty}|z_n|=|z_0|<1$. This is equivalent to the fact that $\exists r_1<1,|z_n|\leq r_1,\forall n\geq 1$. This bound is needed to obtain another inequality:
$$\forall m,n\geq 1,\rho(z_m,z_n)=\frac{|z_m-z_n|}{|1-z_m\overline{z_n}|}\leq\frac{|z_m-z_n|}{1-|z_m||z_n|}\leq\frac{|z_m-z_n|}{1-r_1^2}=:Cd_2(z_m,z_n).\tag{2}$$

[Seeing $(1)$ and $(2)$ combined, one can think that $\rho$ and $d_2$ are equivalent, but $(2)$ is only valid for elements from the given sequence]

Using $z_n\to z_0$ in $(\mathbb{D},d_2)$, we take the limit $m\to\infty$ in $(2)$ to get: $\rho(z_n,z_0)\leq Cd_2(z_n,z_0)$. Now we take the second limit $n\to\infty$ to conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\rho(z_n,z_0)=0 \iff z_n\to z_0$ in $(\mathbb{D},\rho)$, and we are done.